# Why does Pascal have a high code density?

Tags: programming-languages

The plots in http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/06/04/how-the-wolfram-language-measures-up/ seems to indicate that Pascal has a relatively high code density.  What features of the language makes it so?

Follow-up question:

Does this explain why Pascal are often introduced in high schools as one of the first programming languages?

Comment: Although I provided an answer, it has occurred to me that I don't know what you mean by code density. What do you mean?

Comment: @DaveClarke Based on the blog post, the preferred measure of code density is the number of tokens required to implement specific functionality (though a previous study used character count).

Comment: Given that the Wolfram language "wins" by their measurement but is *horrible* to program in, that might not be the best quality metric around.

Comment: @Raphael What's a better metric given Rosetta Stone as input data sets?

Comment: @Problemania: I have no idea! Depends on what you want, I guess. In industry, I'd look at revenue per programmer hour. For academic investigations of elegance, code length may even be appropriate but it has to be done carefully (i.e. selecting fair examples and forbidding [non-standard] library functions).

Comment: There is nothing on the Wolfram page that define density as syntax/semantics ratio, or the inverse. Hence, I cannot read the question, especially since Pascal stands somewhere in the middle. The question should be made more precise.

Answer (score 2):

What makes Pascal dense is not the features it has, but the features it doesn't. Here is a small list of features that make other languages less dense:

- higher order functions
- classes and inheritance
- specialised syntax for sets, lists, hashes
- built in regular expression syntax
- good libraries

Comment: Boilerplate is also a source of code bloat. Having to specify types would also add length.

Comment: Procedures and function can be passed as parameters in Pascal, though
they cannot be returned as results. Still, it should qualify to some
extent as higher-order functions.

Comment: Does your argument explains that Pascal wins over FORTRAN?

Comment: seems good answer to me as it is indeed correct plus the structured form of programming, pascal is known to endorse (which *adds boilerplate code*), makes this even higher